# React router v6 - Outlet not receiving components in nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my routes defined as below.

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="name-the-color" element={<NameTheColor />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

And the Layout component renders the `<Outlet />` component.

```js
const Layout = () => {
  const [crumbPaths, setCrumbPaths] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <BreadcrumbContext.Provider value={{ crumbPaths, setCrumbPaths }}>
        <header>
          {crumbPaths.length > 0 && (
            <ul className={styles.breadCrumbs}>
              {crumbPaths.map(({ label, path }) => (
                <li key={path}>
                  <Link to={path}>{label}</Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </header>
        <Outlet />
      </BreadcrumbContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

There is no error on the browser console or in the webpack build. Still, the `<Outlet />` is unable to render `<Home />` component or `<NameTheColor />` component. I'm not sure how to debug or why is this isn't working. Everything seems to be according to the documentation.

The render tree shows that the Outlet is being rendered but it is probably not receiving the element I want.

[image]

Can anyone point out what I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was due to react-router version 6.1.1 which got automatically upgraded due to my package.json deps mapping to `^6.0.2`.

Changing the mapping to hard dependency on version `6.0.2` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Curious, is there a bug in 6.1.1? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: @Adam Didn’t dive deep on the source code, but looks like a bug as there’s no documentation update. 6.2.0 dropped in a few hours ago. I’ll see if they resolved it in this release.

Comment: @Adam Yep, no issues in 6.2.1. But I once again tried 6.1.1 and this time it worked. ‍♂️ I wonder what the issue was!

Comment: Introduced in [6.1.0](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/v6.1.0) ([PR](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/pull/8461)). Fixed in [6.2.0](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/v6.2.0) ([PR](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/pull/8483))

Comment: I did check the change log. wasn't sure if this was the reason. 
Thanks! will go over these changes.